# On Page Loaded Event

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Is there a way to run code when a view has been loaded as I would like to interact with an element when the page is loaded. I have tried putting the code in the constructor of the component but the view has not been loaded at that point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your routing configuration you can specify an enter handler that is called when the view is loaded:

```dart
'some_view': ngRoute(
    enter: (RouteEnterEvent e) => print('Entering view'))
```

You can find more information on routing events in the [Angular Tutorial](https://angulardart.org/tutorial/08-ch06-view.html).

Comment: I need to be able to subscribe to this event in the controller

Comment: also onenter is called when the page is hit i would like the event to be fired when the view has been loaded

Comment: Do you mean when it's been added to the DOM? I'm not sure if that's easy to do. There is the [AttachAware](https://docs.angulardart.org/#angular/angular-core-annotation.AttachAware) class, but as far as I can tell that only tells you when the component has been initialized, not when everything is loaded into the DOM.

Comment: What i am trying to do is interact with an element that is in the view for the component but obviously that cant be done until the page is loaded